# Elasticsearch query multidimensional array values

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I have these mappings:

```
'indices' => [
    'mappings' => [
        'default' => [
            'properties' => [
                'id' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                ],
                'name' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'english',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I need to store field `stocks` arr[obj]
stock looks like:

```
{stock_id:uint, qty:uint, hidden: bool}
```

Then I need to query this index with search of `name` `where stocks.stock_id IN [1,2,3] and qty>0 and hidden != true`

How I can implement this - does I need to change something in mapping settings?

Btw im using laravel scout with elastic engine under the hood. But your answer will helpful if you show me just raw query

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$query = [
    'bool' => [
        'must' => [
            ['term' => ['id' => $id]],
            ['term' => ['status' => $status]],
            ['range' => ['quantity' => ['gte' => $min_quantity, 'lte' => $max_quantity]]],
        ],
    ],
];

$params = [
    'index' => 'my_model_index',
    'body' => [
        'query' => $query,
    ],
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

For multidimensional array use nested

```
$query = [
    'nested' => [
        'path' => 'my_array',
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['term' => ['my_array.id' => $id]],
                    ['term' => ['my_array.status' => $status]],
                    ['range' => ['my_array.quantity' => ['gte' => $min_quantity, 'lte' => $max_quantity]]],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$params = [
    'index' => 'my_model_index',
    'body' => [
        'query' => $query,
    ],
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```